# Cookie working 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, plugins

I am using the query cookie plugin like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        var user = $('div.popup article.user').html();

        $.cookie('the_cookie', user, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
        message = $.cookie('the_cookie');

        $('section#sidebar_right').html(message);
    });
});
```

So, when user clicks the "close-button", the cookie gets the username and puts it into a specific area, this scenario is created on this site:

domain.com/test.php#close

When i refresh to this site:

domain.com/test.php

The cookie disappear´s (I can see this because the displayed content disappear´s).

Anybody could tell me why?

Greetings

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.close').click(function(){
    var user = $('div.popup article.user').html();

    $.cookie('the_cookie', user, {expires: "7",path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    message = $.cookie('the_cookie');

    $('section#sidebar_right').html(message);
});
```

});

=> still not working, any idea´s ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set lifetime of the cookie, so it's getting deleted on session end.

> https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
>
> expires
>
> expires: 365 Define lifetime of the cookie. Value can be a Number
>   which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date
>   object. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie.

Comment: i edited my question, could you take a look? greetings and thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this problem? It also may be that the server overwrites your cookie.